# How to add a map leader mapping for visual linewise mode in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm having some trouble making this mapping work:

```
if exists(":Tabularize")
  "rails routes file alignment in visual mode
  vmap <Leader>ar :Tabularize /'[^']*'\|=>/l1l0<CR>
endif
```

When I source my vimrc and then:

1. Select several lines with vim's Visual linewise mode (V)
2. Press `\ar`
3. Visual selection is lost, back to Normal mode and the text remains unchanged.

I've tested the Tabularize command and it works. I now want to map it to a leader combination but it just doesn't work through the mapping. Only if I actually input the whole command in vim's CLI.

Note: I've gone through a bunch of map leader questions but none had a solution to my particular issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you need to use `<bar>` instead of `|` in your mapping as `|` separates vim commands.

```
xnoremap <leader>ar :Tabularize /'[^']*'\<bar>=>/l1l0<cr>
```

Some other thoughts:

- you should probably be using `noremap` unless you are using `<Plug>` or `<SID>` mappings.
- You are using `v` mode which maps both visual mode and select mode. It is probably best to use `xnoremap` instead
- You may be interested to know that `:Tabularize` will align all the neighboring lines that match your pattern with out a range
- `:AddTabularPattern` can be used to name a pattern. Add `:AddTabularPattern routes /'[^']*'\<bar>=>/l1l0` to your `~/.vim/after/plugin/tabular.vim`. Now you can do `:Tabularize routes`

Comment: Noted the edit to account for after/plugin. What would be the best approach to map this if I'm using a version controlled vimrc file? I tried adding the :AddTabularPattern line to the vimrc itself but it didn't work. Would prefer to have the patterns in the vimrc file.

Comment: Sadly `:AddTabularPattern` is not available when the `~/.vimrc` is sourced as the tabular plugin is not loaded yet. You can still put your mapping in you vimrc file however the `:AddTabularPattern` probably should go in `~/after/plugin/tabular.vim`. The mapping will look like `xnoremap <leader>ar :Tabularize routes<cr>`. See `:h tabular-scripting`. Note you can also do tricks with the VimEnter autocmd event if you really want to have everything inside your vimrc file. e.g. `autocmd VimEnter * AddTabularPattern routes /'[^']*'\<bar>=>/l1l0`

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much for the suggestions. I think I will add the tabular.vim file to my dotfiles and symlink it from there. A quick edit: Shouldn't it be `~/.vim/after/plugin/tabular.vim` instead of `~/after/plugin/tabular.vim?`

Comment: Good catch. Yes it should