# How can I map consecutive commands to a key

Tags: vim

I set following map in my .vimrc

```
autocmd Filetype markdown xnoremap ms :let i=1<cr> :g/^/s//\=i . '. '/ |let i=i+1<cr>
```

when I open a markdown file,I will get the following error

- E121: Undefined variable: i
- E15: invalid expression i+1

Can you help me to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a map leader mapping for visual linewise mode in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370891/how-to-add-a-map-leader-mapping-for-visual-linewise-mode-in-vim)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663819/how-can-you-map-a-binding-with-a-pipe. TL;DR: the | is interpreted as a separator instead of as a part of the command. Use `<bar>` instead

Answer (score 1):

In `:g/^/<command>`, `<command>` will be executed on *every* selected line so, if `<command>` is a substitution, it might be worthwhile to use a substitution directly instead of `:g`:

```
xnoremap ms :s/^/\=(line('.') - line("'<")) + 1 . '. '/<CR>
```